# Creating a test database through the shell. Missing connection.creation.create_test_db()

Tags: django, django-testing, django-database

The way this is supposed to be done is:

```
from django.db import connection
db = connection.creation.create_test_db() # Create the test db
```

However, the `connection` i import has no methods or attributes. It's type is `django.db.DefaultConnectionProxy`.

In the `django/db/__init__.py` lies the definition:

```
class DefaultConnectionProxy(object):
    """
    Proxy for accessing the default DatabaseWrapper object's attributes. If you
    need to access the DatabaseWrapper object itself, use
    connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS] instead.
    """
    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        return setattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], name, value)
```

I've imported `django.db.connections` and found it has the following attributes/methods:

- connections.all
- connections.databases
- connections.ensure_defaults

no sign of `DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS`.

I'm looking for ideas on how to debug this. Wouldn't want to post a ticket to Django if this has something to do with my configuration.